# Weird XIB file issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nib

Experiencing a weird problem in a modified program written by me. In my first iteration, the view controller had an IBAction by the title userSpecifyingInput and had all my buttons wired up to this IBAction. 
To make the design more sophisticated, I introduced userSpecifyingDigit and userSpecifyingLetter and accordingly had some buttons wiring up to the first IBAction (userSpecifyingDigit) and the next button wiring up to the second IBAction (userSpecifyingLetter).
Upon running my program, it gave me this error:

terminating app: NSInvalidArgumentException
 Unrecognized selector sent to instance

And these selectors were alternating between userSpecifyingInput and userSpecifyingDigit which did not make sense as userSpecifyingInput was completely removed from my ViewControllers interface and implementations.

Now I am not sure why userSpecifyingInput still existed, but after dabbling with sent events, I noticed that the buttons were wired upto the new selectors as well as the old selector. 
I had to manually remove the old selector from the touchupinside events for all the buttons.

Naturally this does not seem to be a very convenient way to go about proceedings and if the view controller selectors are modified then the touch events ought to be automatically removed.

Am I missing something here? This is a pretty open ended question with different answers

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating an IBAction from your implementation will not remove any previous links to it in IB. I haven't heard of any XCode/IB preferences to shortcut this issue.

Comment: so the only way out is to manually eliminate the IBActions from the touch up events for interface elements that were connected to it before?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the xib still thinks one of it's objects is hooked up to the UIViewController, but the function on the UIViewController is no longer there. To check and fix this...

1. Click on the xib file in the project navigator
2. Select the File's Owner
3. Click on the Connections Inspector
4. Verify that none of these connections are invalid

I would also look in the UIViewController to make sure no automagically created references exist here as well.